# Error - Ad Not Available (NoFill) - AdMob SDK Windows Phone 7.1

Tags: admob

I'm trying to add admob sdk to my wp7 project but when i did everything well it gives **Error - Ad Not Available (NoFill)**

Admob app/site settings;
Ad style = Use colors set below:
Automatic refresh: Refrest: 60 seconds
Test mode: Disable test mode for all requests

And also in red circle says: **Inactive: AdMob has never received an ad request for your site.**  because of **Error - Ad Not Available (NoFill)**

I haven't find any articles about how to solve this problem, is this a bug or something like that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem. There is no error.

Admob does not have any inventory for your app in your area. Once you have users across a larger geographic area you will get ad fill.

Comment: I am facing the same issue in android. I can see ad requests from different countries(in admob dashboard), but there is no impression. Logcat always shows the error 'no fill'.

Comment: So again, no problem. This is 100% expected. The way to mitigate it is to use several ad networks and mediate them. Admob provides good mediation out of the box.